# Nginx for main domains and other domains

Tags: nginx

I want to have different server block for my main domain and another block for any other domain that does not match my main domain , how do i do that ?

I tried following , here 1st block is matched for all domains including **mymain.com** .

only sub domains are matching the 2nd server block. example **[www.mymain.com](http://www.mymain.com)** or **admin.mymain.com** etc... how do i make even **mymain.com** to match the 2nd block

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

  location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/thml;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;
     server_name mymain.com;

      location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/admin;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


}
```

P.s : Here any other domains is wildcard , people point my services via cname.

Comment: make your main domain  `server_name mydomain.com` and on the other block, make a `default_server` as `listen 80 default_server;` This will direct requests for your main domain to your first server and any other request to default server

Comment: wild card subdomains too will work on just mydomain.com ?

Comment: It will not work because you put wildcard domains in there but because it is how default server in nginx works. You can only have one default server though, so you need to create another server block with explicit FQDN as `server_name` if you want it to handle requests for certain domain.

Comment: hi please see my updated question , now only sudomains are matching